# While using a struct as elements of a Picker, how can I make the values save when I switch between Picker elements?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI, knowing only c++ to any actual extent. Right now, the functionality is not implemented into the code. The problem I have is that when I set a value to an object used in the picker. Switch to another and come back, the value is not saved. For example, I want to be able to set the hours for each player in the picker, but when I switch it does not save. How could I work around this?

Below is all of my code so far.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Players: Hashable {
    var playerNumber: String
    var killString: String
    var kills: Double
    var hourString: String
    var hours: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var playerList:[Players] = [
        Players(playerNumber: "Player 1", killString: "", kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0),
        Players(playerNumber: "Player 2", killString: "", kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0),
        Players(playerNumber: "Player 3", killString: "", kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0),
        Players(playerNumber: "Player 4", killString: "", kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0),
        Players(playerNumber: "Player 5", killString: "", kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0),
        
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedPlayer: Players = Players(playerNumber: "Player 1", killString: "",
                                                         kills: 0, hourString: "", hours: 0)
    
    @State var hours: String = ""
    @State var kills: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 30){
                Group{
                    Text(selectedPlayer.playerNumber)
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                }.frame(width:350, height: 100)
                    .background(Color("AppSwag")).cornerRadius(30)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Select a Player")
                    .padding(10)
                Picker("Select Player", selection: $selectedPlayer){
                    ForEach(playerList, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0.playerNumber)")
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
                
                
                HStack{
                    
                    Text("Enter Players Hours:")
                    TextField("",text: $hours)
                        .onSubmit {
                            selectedPlayer.hourString = hours
                        }
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                
                HStack{
                    
                    Text("Enter Players Kills:")
                    TextField("",text: $selectedPlayer.killString)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                Text("\(selectedPlayer.playerNumber)'s values: \(selectedPlayer.hourString) ")
            }// Vstack
            .navigationTitle("CSGO Calculator")
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).

Comment: You need a single source of truth, when dealing with value types the selected player is a copy of the one in the array.